# Who earns most, ITPro or Developers?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, .net, office-365-developer

I am at the beginning of my SharePoint career and have two paths I can chose between: ITPRO or developer in SharePoint.

ITpro sounds more interesting, personally.

But I am wondering, who earns most cash in average? ITpros or devs?

Comment: stop -1 my question

Comment: In my opinion, Devs. They should know about as much as IT Pros (they have to), and they know how to develop with SHarePoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, the hierarchical chain is: ITPro, Developer, Architect. The lower you are in this hierarchy, the less you earn.

**EDIT** This is how I interpret these terms:

- *ITPro*: a person who has good windows server, SQL and IIS knowledge; is in charge of the administration of the Sharepoint farm; handles deployments, updates with CUs and SPs; configures the Service Applications of Sharepoint
- *Developer*: writes server or client code according to the best practices of Sharepoint Development; knows a little powershell and a little about configuring the farm.
- *Architect*: a person who can build solutions from the requirements and can advise on the best approach; knows also about networks, authentication methods, IIS and also about best practices in development; can advise developers on the software design and also understands the potential risks or drawbacks of the hardware and network design.

If you are a good developer, you can be also become a pretty good ITPro, it's just about ambition. The other way around is harder and more rare, in my opinion. 
Of course there are ITPros who earn a lot, but I think a developer or an architect with the same years and level of experience will learn even more.

But let's hear what others have to say about this :)

Comment: isnt an architect in SharePoint called ITPro?

Comment: Please see my edited answer